# How do I insert a select all checkbox in mydevexpress gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

I am using the gridview and inserted checkboxes for each row with the gridview feature row selection (http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/RowSelection).
Now I wanted to have a feature to select all checkboxes when some button is clicked, but I can't get it working. I tried googling and found so much answers to this but they're not working for me since I'm fairly new to microsoft visual studio, or I'm probably doing it wrong. I was hoping that you could push me in the right direction.

EDIT: 
I fixed it, it is much more simple as I thought.

SOLUTION:
Add the following to your gridview and you have a selectall function within your gridview:

```
settings.CommandColumn.SetHeaderTemplateContent(c =>
{
    Html.DevExpress().CheckBox(settingsCheckBox =>
    {
        settingsCheckBox.Name = "cbSelectAll";
        settingsCheckBox.Properties.ClientSideEvents.CheckedChanged =
        string.Format("function(s, e) {{ if(s.GetChecked()) {0}.SelectRows(); else {0}.UnselectRows();     }}",
        settings.Name);
        settingsCheckBox.Checked = c.Grid.VisibleRowCount == c.Grid.Selection.Count;
    }).Render();
});
```

I apologize for my bad English.
Thanks,
Marco